# matching / updating UserPrincipal attributes by name from a string using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement

Tags: c#, active-directory, principal

I have a Dictionary whose key/values are UserPrincipal attributes. These are being read in from a csv file. This csv file also has the employeeId of the corresponding AD user to update. The goal is to update each users attributes in AD with the values provided in the csv.

However, I won't know which attributes are supplied in the csv until runtime.

**How can I match each supplied attribute name against the correct UserPrincipal attribute specifically using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and then Update / Save**?

I have an approach using Reflection and 2.0's DirectoryEntry that gets me part of the way there, but still I need a way to update and save:

("userToUpdate" has a reference to a UserPrincipal instance, "Attributes" are the supplied key/values from the csv)

```
 public void UpdateAttributes(List<ADUser> users)
    {           
        // get all the UserPrincipal properties 
        List<string> userPrincipalProperties = 
            users[0].UserPrincipal.GetType().GetProperties()
            .Select(property => property.Name).ToList();

        foreach (var userToUpdate in users)
        {
            try
            {
                 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> attribute in userToUpdate.Attributes
                    .Where(attribute => userPrincipalProperties.Contains(attribute.Key))
                    .Where(attribute =>
                        {
                            return value.ToString() != attribute.Value;
                        }))
                {
                   //something like userToUpdate.UserPrincipal.{property-name} = attribute.Value;

                }
                // save...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
```